# Why is my forEach only displaying one div?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that is holding multiple objects.

```
let myLibrary = [
  {
    title: "The Once and Future King",
    author: "White",
    pages: 654,
  },
  {
    title: "The Hobbit",
    author: "Tolkien",
    pages: 304,
  },
];
```

Using JavaScript I'm attempting to display each object inside its own div.

```
const bookContent = document.getElementById("content");
const addBook = document.createElement("div");

myLibrary.forEach((book) => {
  addBook.className = "book";
  bookContent.appendChild(addBook);
  addBook.innerHTML = `
    <div class="title">
      <p class="bookTitle">
        <span>${book.title}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <p>
        Author: <span>${book.author}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Pages: <span>${book.pages}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
});
```

But for some reason, only one div is showing (The Hobbit). I also have a prompt that asks for a books title, author and page count and creates a new object and pushes to the array

```
function addBookToLibrary() {
  const book = {
    title: prompt("Enter title"),
    author: prompt("Enter author"),
    pages: prompt("Enter pages"),
  };
  myLibrary.push(book);
}
```

but when I fill out that information it overrides the div and still shows only one. How can I fix my code so all objects are shown?

Comment: You need to let `const addBook = document.createElement("div");` inside `forEach`

Comment: You only create one `<div>` (`addBook`). You need to create it inside the loop.

Comment: `.appendChild()` doesn't clone the element you're appending. It appends the element you pass to whatever parent you call `.appendChild()` on.